# Assign a List to a variable of type Element

Tags: java, list, generics, element

Sorry for my poor English in advance. I have this code below :

```
public class test<E> {

    private test<E> element;
    private E[] array;
    private List<E> aList;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

    public test(E[] a_array) {
        array = a_array;
    }

    public test<E> cut(Cut something_cut) { 
        String[] myStrings = new String[] {"Elem1","Elem2","Elem3","Elem4","Elem5"};

        aList = Arrays.asList(array);

        element = alist;  // ??

        return element;
    }
}
```

I would like to, if it's possible, to assign my `List alist` to the variable `element` so therefor I can return it and use it in my main ?

Comment: what are you trying to do here ? Please use the correct cases  for the names. Variable of element is of different type than aList.

Comment: only way you can assign the list back to Test is your Test class implements List.

Comment: Basically i have an Array that gets converted to a list and i would to store that list into my variable element. I am not sure what you mean by changing the cases of my names.

Comment: I mean use Test<E> for test<E> and alist should be referenced as aList. Your variable element with test type can't store the value of list with type List.

Comment: I tried creating a constructor  : public Test(List<E> aList) { 
  this.aList= aList;
  
 } 
but for some reason when i try getting a value out of it it returns me a nullException

Comment: share the code with null pointer exception.

Comment: To convert an array to list test class should have two variables; array and  list variable. In the constructor initialize variables, and then the method to do actually conversion from array to list.

Comment: I actually figure it out thank you for your help and patience very appreciated.